# Trouble to call a method of another class without have to instantiate it

Tags: java, multithreading, class

The function overall should be like this:

- **Work()** of *NodeManager* is a blocking method that call **doYouWork**(counter) on Node[0], and wait
  until method **WorkDone()** it's called by **doyourWork()**
- Node[i] do some work, simulated by Thread.sleep, then if counter is > 0, call **doYourWork** on the
  next *Node* (Nodes order is 0..9->0), or if counter is <=0 *Node* call the method **WorkDone** of *NodeManager*

My problem is that i can't call WorkDone in the class Node without instantiate an object of NodeManager, and i can't even declare WorkDone a static method because then i can't call **NotifyAll**.
What should i do?

```
public class NodeManager implements NodeManager {
    
    private final int N_NODES = 10;
    private static Node[] nodes;
    private int _counter;
    
    public NodeManager(int counter)
    {
        nodes = new Node[N_NODES];
        this._counter = counter;
        
        for(int i=0; i<N_NODES ;)
        {
            nodes[i] = new Node(i, ++i);
        }
        Work(_counter);
    }
    
    public static Node[] getNodes() {
        return nodes;
    }
    
    @Override
    public synchronized void Work(int counter) {
        nodes[0].doYourWork(counter);
        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void WorkDone() {
        notifyAll();
    }   
}
```

and this is Node class

```
public class Node extends AbstractNode {

    private int _id;
    private int _next_id;
    private Node[] nodes;
    
    public Node(int id, int next_id) {
        this._id = id;
        this._next_id = next_id;
        
        if(id == 9)
            this._next_id = 0;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void doYourWork(int counter) {
        
        Random rand = new Random();
        long millis = rand.nextInt((150-100) + 1) + 100;
        
        try {
            Thread.sleep(millis);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        if(counter > 0) {
            nodes = NodeManager.getNodes();
            nodes[_next_id].doYourWork(--counter);
        }
        else {
            //NodeManager.WorkDone(); i would do this
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can call `notifyAll()`, but you would have to call it on a static field. All `wait()`s must, in return, call `wait()` on that static field aswell. `Node[] nodes` is a prime candidate as static object to call `wait()` and `notifyAll()` on. --- If you go down that route, I would suggest to declare `nodes` as `final` (and initialize it statically) to guarantee that this object never changes.

Comment: Java naming conventions start classes with a capital letters; methods and variables start with lower case letters (work, workDone).

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to address a few things about your code first, then see if I can't get to the meat of a solution.

First, please take a peek at Java naming standards. Class names should be UpperCase, as you've done, but method names should be lowerCase, which you seem to do inconsistently.

Second, this is rather odd: public class NodeManager implements NodeManager

You have both a class and an interface named NodeManager. That seems like a really, really bad naming scheme.

Also, this loop makes me squeamish:

```
    for(int i=0; i<N_NODES ;)
    {
        nodes[i] = new Node(i, ++i);
    }
```

This is a future bug waiting to happen. While the code is doing what you want now, this is a dangerous pattern. Nearly always your for-loops should auto-increment inside the for() part. Doing it embedded like this is going to bite you in the ass if you make a habit of this. Please be careful.

And then you also did this:

```
public Node(int id, int next_id) {
    this._id = id;
    this._next_id = next_id;
    
    if(id == 9)
        this._next_id = 0;
}
```

Gross. Pass in the proper next_id. Your node shouldn't magically know you're making 10 of these guys. See previous comment about how you're initializing these guys.

---

As for your solution...

Let's start with NodeManager. You need to decide if you're dealing with static or non-static fields. You're mixing and matching what you're doing. Some of your fields are static, some are not.

Here's what I would do.

1a. I would eliminate the static in the field definitions in NodeManager.
1b. Or, if it's appropriate, I would apply the Singleton pattern to NodeManager, and make it possible to only have 1.

2. I would make it so Node doesn't know a thing about NodeManager.

Now, how do you do #2?

2a. Define an interface called something like NotifyWhenDone. It has a method called workDone.
2b. Node implements NotifyWhenDone.
2c. Pass NodeManager to doYourWork()
2d. doYourWork() expects not a NodeManager object, but a NotifyWhenDone object.
2e. Then instead of NodeManager.workDone(), you call objectToNotify.workDone().

Or there's another solution.

3. Take a look at promises. It's complicated, but it's a GREAT way to do this. Do a Google of Java Promise. It's really probably the right way.

Comment: Yeah i know that's weird doing i++ outside the for() part, i've done only it this time for circumstances. I had to follow the names given by the text of the exam, and it is specified that I cannot use other classes, interfaces besides those present in the text and those explained in class so i can't add interface NotifyWhenDone. About point 3 i don't know what is Java promise but i will look at it.